# Using findAll, List() or SQL Query to return all domain values in a list

Tags: grails, groovy, findall

I'm trying to retrieve all domain values that exist and putting them into a list. I'm using a modal dialogue box to present this list however at the moment all of the values that are retrieved are only values that exist within the instance I'm looking at, instead of retrieving all of them that exist on the database.

So for each Template there are many Steps, that is the relationship we are dealing with. When I open the model dialogue box to retrieve ALL of the Steps on the database, it only shows me the Steps that exist on that Template. Some screenshots may help explain.

Show.gsp page containing the modal dialogue box.

```
<div id="basicModal" title="Existing Template Steps">
    <g:include controller="templateStep" action="renderAllStepsList" />
</div>
```

Controller - Rather than using a service I've tried TemplateStep.findAll("from TemplateStep as ts")  aswell as TemplateStep.list() but they both have the same effect.

```
def renderAllStepsList(){
    def templateStepInstanceList = TemplateStepService.getSuggestedTemplateSteps() 
    render(template:"list", model: [templateStepInstanceList: templateStepInstanceList])
}
```

Service

```
def getSuggestedTemplateSteps() {
    def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    def rows = sql.rows("select distinct * from template_steps")

    def listOfSteps = rows.collect()

    return listOfSteps
   }
 }
```

This is the modal dialogue box currently. As you can see it shows me all of the Steps that exist within the Template instance however I want to retrieve ALL Steps that exist on the database. Is this possible?

[image: Modal]

--*UPDATE*--

Template Domain Class:

```
   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClassProperty
   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsClass

   class Template {

    static notCloneable = ['name']
    static hasMany = [templateSteps:TemplateStep]

    int id
    String name
    String description
    String progressionType
    String defaultPlanType
    String defaultPlanPhase
    String guiFlag
    String extFun

  static mapping = {

    version false
    table 'TEMPLATE'

    id                column: 'SYSID', generator: 'assigned'
    progressionType   column: 'PROGRESSION_TYPE'
    defaultPlanType   column: 'DEFAULT_PLAN_TYPE'
    defaultPlanPhase  column: 'DEFAULT_PLAN_PHASE'
    guiFlag           column: 'GUI_FLAG'
    extFun            column: 'EXT_FUN'
    templateSteps sort :'stepSeq', order:'asc'

}
static constraints = {
    name              (maxSize:250, blank:false, nullable:false, unique:true)
    description       (maxSize:250, blank:true,  nullable:true)
    progressionType   (maxSize:100, blank:true,  nullable:true)
    defaultPlanType   (maxSize:50,  blank:true,  nullable:true) 
    defaultPlanPhase  (maxSize:250, blank:true,  nullable:true) 
    guiFlag           (maxSize:10,  blank:true,  nullable:true)
    extFun            (maxSize:10,  blank:true,  nullable:true)
   }
}
```

Template Step Domain Class:

```
  import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClassProperty
  import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsClass

  class TemplateStep {

   static notCloneable = []
   static belongsTo = [template:Template]
   static hasMany =    [templateInput:TemplateInput,templateOutput:TemplateOutput]//,templateOutputTransDisplayMap:TemplateOutputTransDisplayMap,templateInputTransDisplayMap:TemplateInputTransDisplayMap]

  Long id
  String step
  String validationProcedure
  String actionProcedure
  String transactionTable
  String displayLable
  String windowLable
  String cancelProcedure
  String endPlanPhase
  String mfOutFlag
  Long stepSeq
  String swfName

 static mapping = {

    version false
    table'TEMPLATE_STEPS'

    id                  column: 'SYSID', generator: 'assigned'
    template            column: 'MT_SYSID'
    validationProcedure column: 'VALIDATION_PROCEDURE'
    actionProcedure     column: 'ACTION_PROCEDURE'
    transactionTable    column: 'TRANSACTION_TABLE'
    displayLable        column: 'DISPLAY_LABLE'
    windowLable         column: 'WINDOW_LABLE'
    cancelProcedure     column: 'CANCEL_PROCEDURE'
    endPlanPhase        column: 'END_PLAN_PHASE'
    mfOutFlag           column: 'MFOUT_FLAG'
    stepSeq             column: 'STEP_SEQ' 
    swfName             column: 'SWF_NAME'

 }

 static constraints = {
    step                (maxSize:250, blank:false, nullable:false)
    validationProcedure (maxSize:250, blank:true, nullable:true)
    actionProcedure     (maxSize:250, blank:true, nullable:true)
    transactionTable    (maxSize:250, blank:true, nullable:true)
    displayLable        (maxSize:50,  blank:true, nullable:true)
    windowLable         (maxSize:50,  blank:true, nullable:true)
    cancelProcedure     (maxSize:250, blank:true, nullable:true)
    endPlanPhase        (maxSize:30,  blank:true, nullable:true)
    mfOutFlag           (maxSize:30,  blank:true, nullable:true)
    stepSeq             (maxSize:12,  blank:true, nullable:true)
    swfName             (maxSize:100, blank:true, nullable:true)
    template                         (blank:true, nullable:true)
    }
  }
```

Comment: you must be doing something really wrong here. `TemplateStep.list()` should return all instances. Show your domain class

Comment: That's what I thought too, I've updated the OP with the Template and Template Step domain classes.

Comment: are you sure, you have other rows in your template_step table? compare the output of `TemplateStep.count()` and `select count(*) from template_step`

Comment: TemplateStep.count() returned 6573 when opening the modal dialogue box and select count(*) from template_steps returned 6573 aswell.

Comment: try also `TemplateStep.list().size()`

Comment: print some of the instances out, like `println list[ 0..9 ]` to check that they are full of data

Comment: I used the following which returned all instances of Template Step.  
`templateStepInstanceList.collect{
   println it
  }`

Comment: so, no problem exists?